# Which haml-in-django implementation?

Tags: python, django, haml

I'd rather like to use something like HAML in django, but it seems there are a few alternatives, and I can't really tell the difference between them:

- [hamlpy](https://github.com/jessemiller/HamlPy)
  I'm leaning towards this one, and [djaml](https://github.com/chartjes/djaml) makes it easy to use
- [dmsl](https://github.com/dasacc22/dmsl)
  Also known as 'damsel', not sure how it differs from hamlpy,
  Announced [here](https://dasacc22.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/python-implementation-of-haml/),
  has a [nice looking website](http://dmsl.dasa.cc/) :)
- [shpaml](http://shpaml.webfactional.com/)
  Seems more general, but can be used to generate templates
- [pamela](https://github.com/sebastien/pamela)
  Looks similar to shpaml

Can anyone share their experiences?
Which of these is best/easiest to use with django?
Thanks.

edit: Thanks to [true_religion](http://www.reddit.com/user/true_religion),

- [nemo](https://github.com/9cloud/Nemo)
- [pyhaml](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyHAML)

Answer (score 1):

I think [hamlpy](http://github.com/jessemiller/hamlpy) is the best choice, simple, fast, does all one would expect from an abstraction language. http://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/k9afb/html_the_easy_way/